# After importing bootstrap into app.module.ts, unexpected token < error araises

Tags: angular7, ngx-bootstrap, angular-seed

installed ngx-bootstrap in [angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) 
after that i have imported in app.modules.ts and added additional package in project.config.ts 
then started app using npm start it return unexpected token < issue

> app.modules.ts

```
    import { AlertModule } from "ngx-bootstrap";

    @NgModule({
    imports: [
     AlertModule.forRoot()
      ]})
```

> project.config.ts

```
import { SeedConfig } from './seed.config';
import { ExtendPackages } from './seed.config.interfaces';

export class ProjectConfig extends SeedConfig {

  PROJECT_TASKS_DIR = join(process.cwd(), this.TOOLS_DIR, 'tasks', 'project');

  constructor() {
    super();
    .....

    const additionalPackages: ExtendPackages[] = [
      // required for dev build
      {
        name: 'ngx-bootstrap',
        path: 'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap',
        packageMeta: {
          main: 'bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.min.js',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
      ];
    this.addPackagesBundles(additionalPackages);


  }

}
```

Comment: Could you create a reproduction on Stackblitz?

Comment: [angular-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) clone this repo and try to install ngx-bootstrap in it

Comment: According to the main info, angular-seed lib is [DEPRECATED].